# $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}=\frac{g(x)}{g(y)}$ iff $f(x)=a g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

We have two continuous, nonzero functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, and we are interested in whether or not $$\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}=\frac{g(x)}{g(y)}$$ for all $x$ and $y$. It is obvious that a sufficient condition is that $f(x)=a g(x)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$.  But is this condition also necessary? It would not be necessary without the continuity assumption, but here both $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

Comment: $f(x)=a g(y)$ makes no sense. You probably meant $f(x)=a g(x)$

Comment: I think you mean $f(x)=ag(x)$.

Comment: With the implicit assumption that neither function is ever $0$ this seems to say simply that $f/g$ is constant.

Comment: The functions $f=0$ and $g=1$ satisfies $f(x)=a g(x)$ with $a=0$ but they don't satisfy $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}=\frac{g(x)}{g(y)}$

Comment: @AnneBauval What does that even means? "don't dissatisfy"? The sentence "For all real number $x$ and $y$ we have $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}=\frac{g(x)}{g(y)}$" is either true or false.

Comment: Yes, I meant $f(x)=ag(x)$, and the functions are nonzero.

Comment: Deleting comment after OP clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are nonzero functions and that
$$
\forall x,y\in \mathbb R. \frac{f(x)}{f(y)}=\frac{g(x)}{g(y)}.
$$
Since $f$ and $g$ are never zero, so we can rearrange the equation:
$$
\forall x,y\in \mathbb R. \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(y)}{g(y)}.
$$

In particular, if we fix $y = 0$,
$$
\forall x\in \mathbb R. \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(0)}{g(0)}.
$$

This should address the "necessary" direction of implication.

By the way, I think this contradicts the idea that $f(x)=ag(x)$
would not be necessary without the continuity assumption.

Comment: @AnneBauval No problem.